# Retrieving Facebook User Details with PHP SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an application which uses scope=email, publish_actions, publish_stream so it authorizes to get the user email, among other details.

Problem is that I cannot retrieve it in any way, no matter what code I use... I have been stuck on this for over 4 hours. PHP SDK is 3.2.2 version and yet the examples that comes with it do not work. Have in mind that apps I made last year (April 2012) do not work either. Has anything changed in Graph Api use?

---

### This is from the example.php that do not work either

```
// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

`$user_profile['name']` and `$user_profile['email']` do not return anything...

Comment: Are you able to get any data ?

Comment: Can you post the results of `print_r($user_profile);` ?